# How do I render a table with a checkbox on each row?

Tags: theming, 8

In Drupal 7, I could achieve this using the following code.

```
$form['table'] = array(
  '#type' => 'tableselect',
  '#header' => $header,
  '#options' => $options,
  '#empty' => t('No data')
);
```

This doesn't work anymore in Drupal 8. I just want a page similar to the one at /admin/people. What's the correct way in Drupal 8?

Comment: You can look at his they rendered the /admin/people page

Comment: I think admin/people is a view, in Drupal 8. The OP is asking what is the code that they should use in Drupal 8, and that is equivalent for the Drupal 7 code shown in the question.

Answer (score 2):

The form element type "**tableselect**" is available in Drupal 8

> Description: A table created with a far left column of radios or
>   checkboxes. Build the table headings and columns with the #headers
>   property, and the rows with the #options property.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/8#tableselect

More info on "Adding checkboxes to a table" can be found in the handbook documentation here: https://www.drupal.org/node/945102

Comment: it doesn't work! i tried this:'#type' => 'tableselect',
      '#header' => $header,
      '#options' => $rows,  
      '#multiple' => TRUE,
      '#empty' => $this->t('No data .'),
      ); but the result is empty

Comment: @benson, I suspect it will be an error in your code and not in the core API. Please check the above handbook link and verify your implementation is correct.

Comment: i did read the documentary carefully and tried it many times. Please note it worked perfectly in the Drupal 7. i spent many hours trying to find an example in the Drupal 8 source code and failed to find any module using the tableselect render.

Answer (score 1):

I spent many hours to figure this out and hope my code will help someone to save time.
I am using Drupal 8 version
I was working on some same sort of code where I wanted to output a listing of nodes after form submit and the listing should have checkbox in each row. Below is the sample code. Please modify as per your requirements.

```
$form['mytable'] = array(
    '#type' => 'table',
    '#title' => 'List of Nodes',
    '#header' => ["Checkbox","Title","Author"],
);


$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
        ->condition('status', 1)
        ->execute();
$nodes = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::loadMultiple($nids);
$nids = array_keys($nodes);

// Add input fields in table cells.
$i=0;
foreach($nids as $nid) 
{

  $node = \Drupal\node\Entity\Node::load($nid);
  $contenttitle=$node->title->value;
  $receivername = $node->getOwner()->getDisplayName();
  \Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('node')->resetCache(array($nid));

    $form['mytable'][$i][''] = array(
                                        '#type' => 'checkbox',
                                        '#return_value' => $nid,
                                    );

    $form['mytable'][$i]['Title'] = array(
                                        '#type' => 'label',
                                        '#title' => t($contenttitle),
                                    );
    $form['mytable'][$i]['Author'] = array(
                                        '#type' => 'label',
                                        '#title' => t($receivername),
                                    );
    $i++;
}
// Add a submit button that handles the submission of the form.
$form['actions']['submit'] = [
                                '#type' => 'submit',
                                '#value' => $this->t('Submit'),
                            ];
return $form;
```

below is the output example
[image]

Comment: It looks like you are loading the node twice. Once with all of the nodes, and again inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing that the keys of header and respective keys of option should be same. Either both indexed or both associative.
I face same issue having index key in header and associative key in option which gives empty table.
https://www.drupal.org/node/945102  code will work